# How to restore or clean the Application Menu Unity in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: unity, nautilus, search, appmenu

I have deleted the folder with the files of IntelliJ to make a fresh reinstall, if go to the new folder and run:

```
sh idea.sh
```

It works!

But if I try to run it from the sidebar (I don't know the proper name of it, nor if it is part of Nautilus of Unity, if someone could tell me I would be glad):

[image: Old path found]

.. looks like there is still, somewhere a file, pointing to the old version.

[image]

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like it's showing you a Java file as part of the "document" search in Unity,  which clicking on will try to use the default program associated with Java source files. You may want to see:

[Intellij IDEA launching another icon at start](https://askubuntu.com/questions/856061/intellij-idea-launching-another-icon-at-start)

and

[Update Launcher for Intellij IDEA in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741645/update-launcher-for-intellij-idea-in-ubuntu)

For known issues with the IntelliJ `.desktop` launcher and Unity.

Also take a look at how to create launchers yourself in Unity to run your `idea.sh` script:

[How can I edit/create new launcher items in Unity by hand?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand)

Comment: Thanks, the first one did the trick, I've also read the other links you've provided to understand more about the "tags" inside a `.desktop file`.

Just a quick question: On the first link you've provided the configuration file had somenthing like this at the end:

`X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.22`

Where can I look for this info in my system? Or even, what does it mean X-Desktop-File-Install-Version?

Comment: My understanding is that it's the version of the "FreeDesktop" specification, and the only way I have found to determine what version I have installed is `dpkg -l desktop-file-utils`